# Read lines of a file from the appearance of a pattern onwards

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I have a log that constantly records the activities of an application procedure. I want to read from a line that has a specific occurrence until the end of the file. For example:

```
20180723 15:15:21 Start of execution
20180723 15:15:22 Drawing
20180723 15:19:20 ERROR
20180723 15:15:21 Cutting
. (several lines
. until
. the last)
20180723 16:00:00 Transition
```

I want it to show me from the appearance of a specific chain (in this case **ERROR**) onwards:

```
20180723 15:19:20 ERROR
...
...
...
20180723 16:00:00 Transition --> The last
```

which is to the end of the file at that time. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print only from line which contains `ERROR` to last line (`$`).

```
sed -n '/ERROR/,$p' file
```

---

See: `man sed`